# How do you replace values in a field with max/min values from other fields?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Given *Category*, *Index* and *Date*, I would like to create a new field called *New_Date* as below. *New_Date* would be the *Date* which corresponds with the highest index belonging to the same *Category* for each record.

My data frame has >1m records and 50 fields, so hoping for a more efficient solution than for-loop.

I have looked for similar questions on SO, but most of these questions involved removing the irrelevant records, however I would like to retain all records without removing anything.

Any ideas much appreciated!

```
Category<-c(rep("A",8),rep("B",3),rep("C",4))
Index<-c(seq(1,8),seq(1:3),seq(1:4))
Date<-c("01/01/2020","01/02/2020","01/03/2020","01/04/2020","01/05/2020","01/06/2020","01/07/2020","29/07/2020","01/01/2014","01/02/2014","01/01/2015","01/01/2014","01/01/2015","01/01/2016","01/01/2017")
```

| Category | Index | Date | New_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 01/01/2020 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | 2 | 01/02/2020 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | 3 | 01/03/2020 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | 4 | 01/04/2020 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | 5 | 01/05/2020 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | 6 | 01/06/2020 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | 7 | 01/07/2020 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | 8 | 29/07/2020 | 29/07/2020 |
| B | 1 | 01/01/2014 | 01/01/2015 |
| B | 2 | 01/02/2014 | 01/01/2015 |
| B | 3 | 01/01/2015 | 01/01/2015 |
| C | 1 | 01/01/2014 | 01/01/2017 |
| C | 2 | 01/01/2015 | 01/01/2017 |
| C | 3 | 01/01/2016 | 01/01/2017 |
| C | 4 | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017 |

Regards,
Alch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.table` option -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, New_Date := Date[which.max(Index)], Category]
df
#    Category Index       Date   New_Date
# 1:        A     1 01/01/2020 29/07/2020
# 2:        A     2 01/02/2020 29/07/2020
# 3:        A     3 01/03/2020 29/07/2020
# 4:        A     4 01/04/2020 29/07/2020
# 5:        A     5 01/05/2020 29/07/2020
# 6:        A     6 01/06/2020 29/07/2020
# 7:        A     7 01/07/2020 29/07/2020
# 8:        A     8 29/07/2020 29/07/2020
# 9:        B     1 01/01/2014 01/01/2015
#10:        B     2 01/02/2014 01/01/2015
#11:        B     3 01/01/2015 01/01/2015
#12:        C     1 01/01/2014 01/01/2017
#13:        C     2 01/01/2015 01/01/2017
#14:        C     3 01/01/2016 01/01/2017
#15:        C     4 01/01/2017 01/01/2017
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I had another Category, so the above becomes Category1 and Category2, and another field called "Type", and I only wanted to take the unique combinations of Category1 and Category2 that belonged to a particular "Type"?

Comment: Hmmm...Sorry, this is not clear to me. Can you ask that as a new question?

Comment: Sure, I've posted this as a new question, thanks. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68062008/how-do-you-replace-values-in-a-field-with-max-min-values-from-other-fields-subje

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
df <- data.frame(Category, Index, Date)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$new_date[i] <- df$Date[which.max(as.Date(df$Date[df$Category == df$Category[i]], format = '%d/%m/%Y')) + 
                              which.max(df$Category == df$Category[i]) - 1]
}
```

Comment: thanks, a good option in base.  I'd normally prefer to use base but the data set is really large so am trying to avoid for-loops. good solution in any case!

Answer (score 1):

tidyverse style of doing it.  Actually `last` is not needed to wrap if your index is not duplicate in Categories.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(Category, Index, Date) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(newDate = last(Date[Index == max(Index)]))

#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   Category [3]
#>    Category Index Date       newDate   
#>    <chr>    <int> <chr>      <chr>     
#>  1 A            1 01/01/2020 29/07/2020
#>  2 A            2 01/02/2020 29/07/2020
#>  3 A            3 01/03/2020 29/07/2020
#>  4 A            4 01/04/2020 29/07/2020
#>  5 A            5 01/05/2020 29/07/2020
#>  6 A            6 01/06/2020 29/07/2020
#>  7 A            7 01/07/2020 29/07/2020
#>  8 A            8 29/07/2020 29/07/2020
#>  9 B            1 01/01/2014 01/01/2015
#> 10 B            2 01/02/2014 01/01/2015
#> 11 B            3 01/01/2015 01/01/2015
#> 12 C            1 01/01/2014 01/01/2017
#> 13 C            2 01/01/2015 01/01/2017
#> 14 C            3 01/01/2016 01/01/2017
#> 15 C            4 01/01/2017 01/01/2017
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>