# How do you replace values in a field with max/min values from other fields subject to particular conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

This is an extension of a previous question here: [How do you replace values in a field with max/min values from other fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67934726/how-do-you-replace-values-in-a-field-with-max-min-values-from-other-fields).

Given *Category1, Category2, Type, Index* and *Date*, I would like to create a new field called *New_Date* as below. *New_Date* would be the *Date* which corresponds with the highest *Index* belonging to the each combination of *Category1* and *Category2* subject to another field *Type* being equal to 1.

My data frame has >1m records and 50 fields, so hoping for an *setDT* based solution.

Any ideas much appreciated!

```
Category1<-c(rep("A",8),rep("B",3),rep("C",4))
Category2<-c(rep("X",5),rep("Y",4),rep("Z",6))
Index<-c(seq(1,8),seq(1:3),seq(1:4))
Date<-c("01/01/2020","01/02/2020","01/03/2020","01/04/2020","01/05/2020","01/06/2020","01/07/2020","29/07/2020","01/01/2014","01/02/2014","01/01/2015","01/01/2014","01/01/2015","01/01/2016","01/01/2017")
Type<-c(1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1)
```

| Category1 | Category2 | Index | Date | Type | New_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 | 01/01/2020 | 1 | 01/03/2020 |
| A | X | 2 | 01/02/2020 | 2 | 01/03/2020 |
| A | X | 3 | 01/03/2020 | 1 | 01/03/2020 |
| A | X | 4 | 01/04/2020 | 2 | 01/03/2020 |
| A | X | 5 | 01/05/2020 | 2 | 01/03/2020 |
| A | Y | 6 | 01/06/2020 | 1 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | Y | 7 | 01/07/2020 | 1 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | Y | 8 | 29/07/2020 | 1 | 29/07/2020 |
| B | Y | 1 | 01/01/2014 | 1 | 01/01/2014 |
| B | Z | 2 | 01/02/2014 | 2 | 01/01/2015 |
| B | Z | 3 | 01/01/2015 | 1 | 01/01/2015 |
| C | Z | 1 | 01/01/2014 | 1 | 01/01/2017 |
| C | Z | 2 | 01/01/2015 | 2 | 01/01/2017 |
| C | Z | 3 | 01/01/2016 | 2 | 01/01/2017 |
| C | Z | 4 | 01/01/2017 | 1 | 01/01/2017 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Type = 1` get the `Date` corresponding to `max` `Index` for `Category1` and `Category2`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, New_Date := Date[match(max(Index[Type == 1]), Index)], .(Category1, Category2)]
df

#    Category1 Category2 Index       Date Type   New_Date
# 1:         A         X     1 01/01/2020    1 01/03/2020
# 2:         A         X     2 01/02/2020    2 01/03/2020
# 3:         A         X     3 01/03/2020    1 01/03/2020
# 4:         A         X     4 01/04/2020    2 01/03/2020
# 5:         A         X     5 01/05/2020    2 01/03/2020
# 6:         A         Y     6 01/06/2020    1 29/07/2020
# 7:         A         Y     7 01/07/2020    2 29/07/2020
# 8:         A         Y     8 29/07/2020    1 29/07/2020
# 9:         B         Y     1 01/01/2014    1 01/01/2014
#10:         B         Z     2 01/02/2014    2 01/01/2015
#11:         B         Z     3 01/01/2015    1 01/01/2015
#12:         C         Z     1 01/01/2014    1 01/01/2017
#13:         C         Z     2 01/01/2015    2 01/01/2017
#14:         C         Z     3 01/01/2016    2 01/01/2017
#15:         C         Z     4 01/01/2017    1 01/01/2017
```