# How do you replace values in a field with max/min values from other fields subject to particular conditions? Allowing for duplicated conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

This is an extension of a previous question here: [How do you replace values in a field with max/min values from other fields subject to particular conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68062008/how-do-you-replace-values-in-a-field-with-max-min-values-from-other-fields-subje).

Given `Category1`, `Category2`, `Type`, `Index` and `Date`, I would like to create a new field called `New_Date` as below. `New_Date` would be the Date which corresponds with the highest `Index` belonging to the each combination of `Category1` and `Category2` subject to another field `Type` being equal to 1.

My `data` has >1m records and 50 fields.

**Note:** the difference to the other issue linked above, is that the `Index` field may not be unique.  In cases where they are duplicated, we would need to return the latest `max(Date)`.

```
Category1 <-c (rep("A",8),rep("B",3),rep("C",4))

Category2 <-c (rep("X",5),rep("Y",4),rep("Z",6))

Index <- c(rep(1,8),seq(1:3),seq(1:4))

Date <- c("01/01/2020","01/02/2020","01/03/2020","01/04/2020","01/05/2020","01/06/2020","01/07/2020","29/07/2020","01/01/2014","01/02/2014","01/01/2015","01/01/2014","01/01/2015","01/01/2016","01/01/2017")

Type <- c(1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1)
```

| Category1 | Category2 | Index | Date | Type | New_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 | 01/01/2020 | 1 | 01/03/2020 |
| A | X | 2 | 01/02/2020 | 2 | 01/05/2020 |
| A | X | 1 | 01/03/2020 | 1 | 01/03/2020 |
| A | X | 4 | 01/04/2020 | 2 | 01/05/2020 |
| A | X | 5 | 01/05/2020 | 2 | 01/05/2020 |
| A | Y | 6 | 01/06/2020 | 1 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | Y | 7 | 01/07/2020 | 1 | 29/07/2020 |
| A | Y | 8 | 29/07/2020 | 1 | 29/07/2020 |
| B | Y | 1 | 01/01/2014 | 1 | 01/01/2014 |
| B | Z | 2 | 01/02/2014 | 2 | 01/01/2015 |
| B | Z | 3 | 01/01/2015 | 1 | 01/01/2015 |
| C | Z | 1 | 01/01/2014 | 1 | 01/01/2017 |
| C | Z | 2 | 01/01/2015 | 2 | 01/01/2017 |
| C | Z | 3 | 01/01/2016 | 2 | 01/01/2017 |
| C | Z | 4 | 01/01/2017 | 1 | 01/01/2017 |

Using the code below as suggested by [Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah)

```
setDT(df)[, New_Date := Date[match(max(Index[Type == 1]), Index)], .(Category1, Category2)]
```

In the third row, `R` would match with the first occurrence, and the `New_Date` would be `01/01/2020` instead of `01/03/2020`.

Any suggestions or slight alterations to the code above are much appreciated!

Comment: Would Row 1 and Row 3 of new_date be the same?  i.e. should new_date in Row 1 be 01/01/2020 or 01/03/2020?

Comment: The logic to get the expected output is a bit unclear. Can you confirm if the `new_Date` is properly calculated for the two rows before the last one in the expected output table? Shouldn't the value be `01/01/2016` instead of `01/01/2017`

Comment: The issue may be that "Index" in row 3 should read "3" and not "1" and `Index<-c(rep(1,8),seq(1:3),seq(1:4))` should be `Index<-c(seq(1,8), seq(1:3), seq(1:4))`

Comment: Eeeek. I apologise @Tech Commodities, you are quite right, the code snippet I used was incorrect.  It should be `Index<-c(1,2,1,4,5,6,7,8, seq(1:3), seq(1:4))`.  Basically it is a copy of the previously-linked issue, but a minor tweak on the 3rd row to show that the Index field can be duplicated.  And yes, it is correct that New_Date for Rows 1 and 3 should be 01/03/2020, this is the intention.

@B.ChristianKamgang and yes, you are right, the previous two rows before the bottom row should say 01/01/2016. Apologies

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem using the package `data.table`.

```
setDT(df)[, New_Date := max(Date[Index==max(Index)]), by=.(Category1, Category2, Type==1)]
 
#     Category1 Category2 Index       Date  Type   New_Date
#  1:         A         X     1 01/01/2020     1 01/03/2020
#  2:         A         X     2 01/02/2020     2 01/05/2020
#  3:         A         X     1 01/03/2020     1 01/03/2020
#  4:         A         X     4 01/04/2020     2 01/05/2020
#  5:         A         X     5 01/05/2020     2 01/05/2020
#  6:         A         Y     6 01/06/2020     1 29/07/2020
#  7:         A         Y     7 01/07/2020     2 01/07/2020
#  8:         A         Y     8 29/07/2020     1 29/07/2020
#  9:         B         Y     1 01/01/2014     1 01/01/2014
# 10:         B         Z     2 01/02/2014     2 01/02/2014
# 11:         B         Z     3 01/01/2015     1 01/01/2015
# 12:         C         Z     1 01/01/2014     1 01/01/2017
# 13:         C         Z     2 01/01/2015     2 01/01/2016
# 14:         C         Z     3 01/01/2016     2 01/01/2016
# 15:         C         Z     4 01/01/2017     1 01/01/2017
```

Here is the `dplyr` approach:

```
df %>%  
  group_by(Category1, Category2, Type==1) %>% 
  mutate(New_Date = max(Date[Index==max(Index)])) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-`Type == 1`)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use the Tidyverse, I think this gives what you're looking for:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(Category1 = c(rep("A",8),rep("B",3),rep("C",4)),
             Category2 = c(rep("X",5),rep("Y",4),rep("Z",6)),
             Index = c(1,2,1,4,5,6,7,8, seq(1:3), seq(1:4)),
             Date = c("01/01/2020","01/02/2020","01/03/2020","01/04/2020","01/05/2020","01/06/2020","01/07/2020","29/07/2020","01/01/2014","01/02/2014","01/01/2015","01/01/2014","01/01/2015","01/01/2016","01/01/2017"),
             Type = c(1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1)

df |>
  dplyr::group_by(Category1, Category2, Index) |>
  dplyr::mutate(new_date = max(Date))

# A tibble: 15 x 6
# Groups:   Category1, Category2, Index [14]
   Category1 Category2 Index Date        Type new_date  
   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     
 1 A         X             1 01/01/2020     1 01/03/2020
 2 A         X             2 01/02/2020     2 01/02/2020
 3 A         X             1 01/03/2020     1 01/03/2020
 4 A         X             4 01/04/2020     2 01/04/2020
 5 A         X             5 01/05/2020     2 01/05/2020
 6 A         Y             6 01/06/2020     1 01/06/2020
 7 A         Y             7 01/07/2020     2 01/07/2020
 8 A         Y             8 29/07/2020     1 29/07/2020
 9 B         Y             1 01/01/2014     1 01/01/2014
10 B         Z             2 01/02/2014     2 01/02/2014
11 B         Z             3 01/01/2015     1 01/01/2015
12 C         Z             1 01/01/2014     1 01/01/2014
13 C         Z             2 01/01/2015     2 01/01/2015
14 C         Z             3 01/01/2016     2 01/01/2016
15 C         Z             4 01/01/2017     1 01/01/2017
          )
```